# Conflict in interpretation of “dharma”

Tags: krishna, bhagavad-gita, dharma, arjuna

We know of the verse in Bhagavad Gita

> Yada yada hi dharmasya...

But then Sri Krishna also exhorts Arjuna to leave all dharma and surrender to Him alone.

So if Sri Krishna descends to protect Dharma ,what is the point of asking Arjuna to leave all Dharma and surrender to Him?

Comment: This is a good question. People often misunderstand the Gita from which Arjuna got the courage to fight and do his dharma. From Abhinavagupta and Ramanujacharya’s commentary. *‘Relinquishing all Dharmas means the complete relinquishment of the sense of agency, possessiveness, fruits etc... It means that relinquishment **is not of all devotional duties** but only of the **sense of agency and the fruits**. This is the Sastraic relinquishment of all Dharmas.’* - it doesn’t mean one must stop fighting, etc. One must rely on God and do karma based on his guidance

Comment: @Archit Good answer, you should make that as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

your perception is wrong here
krishna never asked arjuna to leave his kshatriya dharma instead he was convincing him to follow his dharma otherwise it will lead you to defame and cowardice
NOW ANSWER TO YOUR QUESTION
here surrender means is to give control of your indriyas(senses) to krishna and let him be your guide, but not dhrma your duties towards nation